# iFrame, Canvas, Fixed Width, Content ist center and not right aligned

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, width, fixed

I could not find an anwser to my question, beside it is hard to explain it in a few words.

my FB App is an iFrame Canvas, when I set the width to "fluid" the top status bar is left aligned.
when I change to fixed width, I am expecting that I got the same layout like FB always is, the status bar centerd, and my app next to the realtime app activity tab.
But the FB layout is still like "fluid" and my content is fixed width (760px) and is centerd, so I have white space all around it.

I want just the normal FB Layout, statusbar centered, my content is centered right next to it should be the activity tab and only left from my content should be whitespace.

Can anyone tell me how i can set it up right?

Here some screenshots to clarify:

expected: http://oi39.tinypic.com/t88dat.jpg

fixed: http://i40.tinypic.com/24drivk.jpg

fluid: http:// i44.tinypic.com/2po31tt.jpg

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try having the body style be `{position: relative; left: someValue;}`, where `someValue` is calculated based on the window width. So it would be something like `someValue=(windowWidth - facebookSidebarWidth - yourcontentWidth) / 2`;

I think you can subscribe to the window resize event and dynamically change the left float value according to the above.